# Failed download URL ftom Firebase

Tags: url, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I have a problem with Firebase. I make a simple app that upload image in Firebase storage. I would like to download URL of the image with `getDownloadUrl()` method. But when I test app it gives me back the `addOnFailureListener()` and not download the URL. the same chose is when I use delete. I don't understand what I'm wrong. Can someone help me? thanks

```
 storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mStorage = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://name-firebase.appspot.com");



private void downloadDataViaUrl() {
    mPregresDialog.show();
    mStorage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            mPregresDialog.dismiss();
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(mImageView);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            mPregresDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}

private void deleteFile() {
   mPregresDialog.show();
    StorageReference file = mStorage.child("images/account.jpg");
    file.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            mPregresDialog.dismiss();
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
           mPregresDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the exception you receive in the different cases? Please add it to the question.

Comment: In your Url you havent specified a certain Image you  want to download , you are just pointing in the bucket without any specification of an image.

Comment: how do I specify the url of an image?

Comment: Suppose you have an image in your bucket called green.jpg you say **mStorage = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://name-firebase.appspot.com/green.jpg");**      There you are pointing on an Image called green.jpg

Comment: ahh ok!!! i undestand now! but if i capture an image, and i don't know his name, 
how can I delete it later? I can not? thanks!!!